# i18n with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I have integrated in my project Internationalization (i18n) library, and I have some problems with Ist an second segments. I have routes:

```
$route['^(en|ru)/services'] = 'services';
$route['^(en|ru)/services/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'services/showcat/$1/$2';
$route['^(en|ru)/services/(:any)'] = 'services/showcat/$1';
```

some links work perfectly lake `site.pc/en/services` bat when I enter `site.pc/en/services/private_service` or `site.pc/en/services/private_service/idart` I can't get params what I ned, it given to me that

```
public function showcat($idCat, $idart = '') {
        echo ' id: ' . $idCat;      // en

        //and for http://site.pc/en/services/private_service/3
        echo ' idart: ' . $idServise;     // empty
}
```

Why I can't get idCat = private_service and idart = 3

if I add in array controller services to not localized

// special URIs (not localized)
    var $special = array (
        "dashboard",
        "settings",
        "services"
    );
in class MY_Lang then i get good parameters get idCat = private_service and idart = 3

To get my parameters I need to ad  in routes 3rd params

```
$route['^(en|ru)/services/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'services/showcat/$1/$2/$3';
```

and in function

```
//url is site.pc/en/services/private_service/3/anyvars    
function showcat($idCat, $idart = '', $k = '') {
    //idCat is en
    //idart is private_service
    //k is 3
    }
```

Why firs parameter is get lang

Comment: possible duplicate of [18n problemm with segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218830/18n-problemm-with-segments)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

It seems first ID in rout is one of this (en|ru) so in my routes line it has to be that

```
$route['^(en|ru)/services/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'services/showcat/$2/$3/$4';
```